# Vue and Quasar Logarithmic Slider

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, quasar-framework, quasar

I'm working on a project with Vue 2 and Quasar 1 and I'm trying to create a logarithmic slider. I've gotten a basic example working with a native input slider here in this code pen:
https://codepen.io/tonycarpenter/pen/ZEVKWbr?editors=1111

```
function calculateLogarithmicSlider(min, max, sliderPosition) {
  const minimumSliderValue = Math.log(min);
  const maximumSliderValue = Math.log(max);
  const sliderScale = (maximumSliderValue-minimumSliderValue) / (100);
  return Math.exp(minimumSliderValue + sliderScale*(sliderPosition));
}

function calculateSliderValue (min, max, sliderPosition) {
    return Math.round(calculateLogarithmicSlider(min, max, sliderPosition));
}

const smartRange = {
    props: ['min', 'max'],
    template:
`
    <div>
        <label> MIN: {{ min }} MAX: {{ max }} <label>
        <input v-on:input='update($event)' type='range'>
    </div>
`,
    methods: {
        update(event) {
            const sliderPosition = parseInt(event.target.value)            
            const sliderValue = calculateSliderValue(this.min, this.max, sliderPosition)
            this.$emit('change', sliderValue)
        }
    }
}


const app = new Vue({
    el: document.querySelector('#app'),
    components: { smartRange },
    data: {
        value: 0
    },
    methods: {
        updateVal(newVal) { this.value = newVal }
    }
})
```

How do I bind this logic with this Quasar slider + tooltip that follows the exponential increase when sliding?
https://codepen.io/tonycarpenter/pen/bGOWXKG

The closest solution I've found online is this one using a Quasar range slider with Vue 3 and Quasar 2, and I don't understand the finer points of Vue 2 vs Vue 3:
https://codepen.io/pdanpdan/pen/XWYPZMq?editors=1111

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: check this : https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/blob/dev/docs/src/examples/QSlider/Step.vue

Answer (score 1):

I have made this slider for you. you can go there and see.

https://codepen.io/prince_61/pen/ZEVyQBQ

```
<div id="q-app" style="min-height: 100vh;">
  <div class="q-pa-md">
    <q-badge color="secondary">
      Model: {{ redModel }} (0 to 100, step 100)
    </q-badge>
    <q-slider
      v-model="redModel"
      color="red"
      :step="1"
    ></q-slider>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
const { ref } = Vue

const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup () {
    return {
      redModel: ref(25),
    }
  }
})

app.use(Quasar, { config: {} })
app.mount('#q-app')
```

Comment: The OP wants the value to increase exponentially and not at a constant step of `1`.

Comment: Yeah I wanted the value to increase exponentially like Prerak said (you can see my original codepen example for the behavior I'm trying to implement). Thanks for trying though!